# Why/when TypeLib should be registered?

Tags: com, registry, interop, com-interop, typelib

This is what I think I know:

- TypeLib only descripes "what should be out there" (=How to locate and call the actual class)
- If .tlb -file (=TypeLib) is imported in C++ -code at compile time, the compiled code already contains all information "what should be out there".
- Interop -assembly (.NET) is pretty much the same as .tlb -file. It's only in assembly-form so that the .NET code can be compiled against it, but also contains info only about "what should be out there".
- If interop in embedded, its TypeLib-info is included in the assembly and there's no need to deploy separate interop-dll when the application is deployed.
- If the interop is not embedded, the interop-dll must be deployed to the same folder as the calling assembly so that the info can be found by the caller.

Of course the actual classes that the TypeLib is pointing to must be registered so that they can be found from the depth of the machine with the TybeLib-info.

Please correct me, if something above is wrong.

My question is, based on above "knowledge", why I sometimes see articles/questions/tutorials about REGISTERING TYPELIBs? It just doesn't make any sense to me (yet), since registering them shouldn't provide any excess information for the caller.

Thank you.

Comment: A type library is often used for marshaling support of interfaces it describes. For that, it must be registered.

Comment: I'll add details to @IgorTandetnik's comment: you can have marshaling without a typelib. You can implement `IMarshal` or use proxy-stubs instead. However it's often convenient to make use of so-called *Automation marshaling* which only works with a set of requirements met (those can be met quite often) *and* uses a registered typelib.